# Google Analytics claims a conversion rate of 100%, which makes no sense

Tags: google-analytics

I wanted to see how many people were going from my company's website, `CarouselApps.com` to one of my products' website, `Screensaver.Ninja`, so in Google Analytics I created a conversion goal in CarouselApps:

[image]

but the report makes no sense, it's claiming that everybody that visits `CarouselApps.com` also visited `Screensaver.Ninja`, which is highly unlikely:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

As it's now configured, your goal is counting all visits to `screensaver.ninja` as a conversion. So naturally, conversions / visits = 100%

You really don't need goals at all to track visits from a traffic source. Instead, it probably makes sense to simply count the number of `carouselapps.com` referrals from within your Google Analytics property for `screensaver.ninja`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on how many people are we talking about, I'd there's one person that visited the website, he might have also visited the other and that's why is 100%